# Python statsmodel VARMAX Results

Tags: python, statsmodels

Everytime I run a VARMAX model I get different coefficients.
Is there any way I could replicate my previous results without imposing a seed?
Thank you

I tried to replicate the VARMA(p,q) example posted on the statsmodels webpage: ( https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_varmax.html ). In order to check the replicability of the results, I just added a loop to reestimate the model and a dataframe (parameters) for saving the results. So this is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dta = sm.datasets.webuse('lutkepohl2', 'https://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/')
dta.index = dta.qtr
endog = dta.loc['1960-04-01':'1978-10-01', ['dln_inv', 'dln_inc', 'dln_consump']]


exog = endog['dln_consump']

parameters=pd.DataFrame()
for p in  range(10):
    print(p)
    mod = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog[['dln_inv', 'dln_inc']], order=(1,1))
    res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
    print(res.summary())
    param= pd.DataFrame(res.params,columns= ["estimation "+str(p)])
    parameters=pd.concat([parameters, param], axis=1)

print(parameters)
```

As you can see, the results change everytime I reestimate the model:

```
                          estimation 0  estimation 1  estimation 2  \
const.dln_inv                 0.010974      0.010934      0.010934   
const.dln_inc                 0.016554      0.016536      0.016536   
L1.dln_inv.dln_inv           -0.010164     -0.010087     -0.010087   
L1.dln_inc.dln_inv            0.360306      0.362187      0.362187   
L1.dln_inv.dln_inc           -0.032975     -0.033071     -0.033071   
L1.dln_inc.dln_inc            0.230657      0.231421      0.231421   
L1.e(dln_inv).dln_inv        -0.249916     -0.250307     -0.250307   
L1.e(dln_inc).dln_inv         0.125546      0.125581      0.125581   
L1.e(dln_inv).dln_inc         0.088878      0.089001      0.089001   
L1.e(dln_inc).dln_inc        -0.235258     -0.235176     -0.235176   
sqrt.var.dln_inv              0.044926      0.044927      0.044927   
sqrt.cov.dln_inv.dln_inc      0.001670      0.001662      0.001662   
sqrt.var.dln_inc              0.011554      0.011554      0.011554
```

Comment: Can you post what you already have tried (code) and the errors please ?

Comment: This should not in general happen since the optimizers should be deterministic, but it's impossible to tell exactly what's going on from the code you've posted.You would probably need to post a fully replicable example, including the dataset and all of the code you're using.  You might want to post a Github issue on the statsmodels (although there you would also need a fully replicable example).

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried to replicate the example posted on the statsmodels webpage and I still find that the VARMA(p,q) model returns different results everytime I reestimate it.  I have post an answer with the details, code, coefs, ...
Thank you

Comment: I only get the very same results if I select a small number of 'maxiter' (ie. 50)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. But I tried to replicate the VARMA(p,q) example posted on the statsmodels webpage: ( https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_varmax.html ).  In order to check the replicability of the results, I just added a loop to reestimate the model and a dataframe (parameters) for saving the results. So this is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dta = sm.datasets.webuse('lutkepohl2', 'https://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/')
dta.index = dta.qtr
endog = dta.loc['1960-04-01':'1978-10-01', ['dln_inv', 'dln_inc', 'dln_consump']]


exog = endog['dln_consump']

parameters=pd.DataFrame()
for p in  range(10):
    print(p)
    mod = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog[['dln_inv', 'dln_inc']], order=(1,1))
    res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
    print(res.summary())
    param= pd.DataFrame(res.params,columns= ["estimation "+str(p)])
    parameters=pd.concat([parameters, param], axis=1)

print(parameters)
```

As you can see, the results change everytime I reestimate the model:

```
                          estimation 0  estimation 1  estimation 2  \
const.dln_inv                 0.010974      0.010934      0.010934   
const.dln_inc                 0.016554      0.016536      0.016536   
L1.dln_inv.dln_inv           -0.010164     -0.010087     -0.010087   
L1.dln_inc.dln_inv            0.360306      0.362187      0.362187   
L1.dln_inv.dln_inc           -0.032975     -0.033071     -0.033071   
L1.dln_inc.dln_inc            0.230657      0.231421      0.231421   
L1.e(dln_inv).dln_inv        -0.249916     -0.250307     -0.250307   
L1.e(dln_inc).dln_inv         0.125546      0.125581      0.125581   
L1.e(dln_inv).dln_inc         0.088878      0.089001      0.089001   
L1.e(dln_inc).dln_inc        -0.235258     -0.235176     -0.235176   
sqrt.var.dln_inv              0.044926      0.044927      0.044927   
sqrt.cov.dln_inv.dln_inc      0.001670      0.001662      0.001662   
sqrt.var.dln_inc              0.011554      0.011554      0.011554
```

Comment: I ran your example code and could not replicate your results - I get the same estimates every time. You could post your question to the Statsmodels bug tracker, along with details of your installation.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran my code again and I still find different results: For example, I got 3 different coefs (out of 10 estimations) for the first variable ('const.dln_inv  ') saved in the first row of the dataframe 'parameters'. I got 0.010974 , 0.010934 and  0.010920
I will post my question to Statsmodels on GitHub.